# dynamically adding values to a drop down list-WinCC Flexible 2008

Tags: vbscript, plc

I am looking for a way of creating a dynamic symbolic i/o field to show and be able to select files that are placed inside a folder on the HMI PC. As the number of files inside the folder changes it needs to be dynamic (200+ PDF files). I am currently thinking

Use VBS script to find all files in a folder
Populate a drop down menu
I am having trouble with populating a drop down menu, i was expecting that i can add items through the visual basic script but for the life of me (and through several google searches) i cant just add items through VBS script. I may be "thinking" or looking at this the wrong way. I though it would be just something along the lines of

'----------------------------------------------------Code-Pseudo

Dim ObjScreenItem

Set ObjScreenItem=HmiRuntime.ActiveScreen.ScreenItems("DropDown")

ObjScreenItem.dataSet.add("FILENAME1")....etc

---

How do i actually access the drop down list through a script??

Regards,

Alec

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Siemens has already published a simple guide on how to do that.
There is also a simple project tha you can download...

*You can create dynamic text lists by inserting tags (variables) or other text lists.
Then you can write the desired values to these tags and your symbolic i/o field will be updated with these values.
You must know the order of the tags so you can "find" which is selected when user will select one of the fields of the symbolic i/o field.*

I send you the link:

https://support.industry.siemens.com/cs/document/33317203/how-do-you-create-dynamic-text-lists?dti=0&lc=en-DE

Answer (score 1):

The document linked to by RammRras contains the following:

> Note:
> The number of entries in the text lists is predefined by the configuration of the text lists.

I interpret that to mean that BigAl's request for

> ObjScreenItem.dataSet.add("FILENAME1")

can't be performed using text lists.

I am having the same problem. From what I can tell Siemens is trying to upsell to their "Pro" version.